# Polmorphism application problem in C language

Tags: c, oop, polymorphism

this is my first question in stackowerflow. So i'm excited :)
I am trying to practice polymorphism in C. I have read many articles. I wrote a small sample code with what I understood. my goal is to create one shape class. this class includes field and length methods. The rectangle and circle classes that derive from this class make their own calculation of the field and length methods.

But there is a problem during compilation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCZGP.png)
Exception thrown at 0x000000000000000A in OOP_in_C_example_3_polymorphism_3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x000000000000000A.

it gets better when I delete one of the lines. but this time it operates according to the last called constructor:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcHoj.png)

Where am I having problems?

shape.h:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct Vtable;

typedef struct{
    struct Vtable* vptr;
    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t y;

}Shape;

struct Vtable {
    void(*area)(Shape* me);
    void(*lenght)(Shape* me);
};

inline void area(Shape* me) {
    (*me->vptr->area)(me);
}

inline void lenght(Shape* me) {
    (*me->vptr->lenght)(me);
}

void shape_ctor(Shape* me, int x, int y);
```

shape.c:

```
#include "shape.h"

void shape_ctor(Shape* me,int x, int y) {   
    struct Vtable vtbl = { &area,&lenght };
    me->vptr = &vtbl;
    me->x   = x;
    me->y   = y;
}
```

rect.h:

```
#include "shape.h"

typedef struct  {
    Shape super;
    uint16_t en;
    uint16_t boy;
}rect;

void rect_ctor(rect* me, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t en, uint16_t boy);
```

rect.c:

```
#include "rect.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void rect_lenght(void* me);
void rect_area(void* me);


void rect_ctor(rect* me,uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t en, uint16_t boy) {
    struct Vtable vtbl = { &rect_area, &rect_lenght };
    
    shape_ctor(&me->super, x, y);
    me->super.vptr = &vtbl;                 //override vptr
    me->en  = en;
    me->boy = boy;
}


void rect_lenght(void* me) {
    rect* me_ = (rect*)me;      //downcast işlemi
    printf("rectangle lenght: %d\n",(me_->en + me_->boy) * 2);
}
void rect_area(void* me) {
    rect* me_ = (rect*)me;      //downcast işlemi
    printf("rectangle area: %d\n", (me_->en)*(me_->boy));
}
```

circle.h:

```
#include "shape.h"

typedef struct {
    Shape super;
    uint16_t radius;
}circle;


void circle_ctor(circle* me, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t r);
```

circle.c:

```
#include "circle.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void circle_lenght(void* me);
void circle_area(void* me );


void circle_ctor(circle* me, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t r) {
    struct Vtable vtbl = {&circle_area,&circle_lenght};

    shape_ctor(&me->super, x, y);
    me->super.vptr = &vtbl;
    me->radius = r;
}


void circle_lenght(void* me) {
    circle* me_ = (circle*)me;
    printf("circle lenght: %f\n", (me_->radius) * (2) * (3.14));
}
void circle_area(void* me){
    circle* me_ = (circle*)me;
    printf("circle area: %f\n", (me_->radius) * (me_->radius) * (3.14));
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "rect.h"
#include "circle.h"


int main() {
    rect  k1;
    circle d1;

    rect_ctor(&k1, 10, 10, 15, 20);
    circle_ctor(&d1, 10, 10, 5);
    
    
    k1.super.vptr->lenght(&k1);
    d1.super.vptr->lenght(&d1);
}
```

Comment: Please add errors as text not images. Errors looks like runtime exceptions not compilation errors.

Comment: `But there is a problem during compilation: enter image description here`: it seems his is during execution, not compilation, anyway I cannot understand how you can compile that code without error

Comment: An access violation means you are writing to a location in memory that you do not own.  Look for buffers that were created too small for what you are writing to them, or pointers to which are not assigned memory.  And, I agree with the first commenter, Please consider editing your code to include the error message(s) in the post as text, not hidden in a link to a picture.  btw, `lenght` is spelled `length` :) Otherwise, very well done question. (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there is a problem during compilation: enter image description here

This was during the execution time, not during the compilation

You have undefined behaviors because you use the address of local variable after you leave the functions, you need to replace

```
void shape_ctor(Shape* me,int x, int y) {   
    struct Vtable vtbl = { &area,&lenght };
```

by

```
void shape_ctor(Shape* me,int x, int y) {   
    static struct Vtable vtbl = { &area,&lenght };
```

and

```
void circle_ctor(circle* me, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t r) {
    struct Vtable vtbl = {&circle_area,&circle_lenght};
```

by

```
void circle_ctor(circle* me, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t r) {
    static struct Vtable vtbl = {&circle_area,&circle_lenght};
```

I had to move the definition of *area* and *length* from *shape.h* to *shape.c*, and I removed the useless *inline* for them.

I also had to protect the headers against the multiple inclusions, example :

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

#include <stdint.h>

struct Vtable;

typedef struct{
    struct Vtable* vptr;
    uint16_t x;
    uint16_t y;
}Shape;

struct Vtable {
    void(*area)(Shape* me);
    void(*lenght)(Shape* me);
};

void shape_ctor(Shape* me, int x, int y);

#endif
```

After that, compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall -g *.c
circle.c: In function 'circle_ctor':
circle.c:9:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     static struct Vtable vtbl = {&circle_area,&circle_lenght};
                   ^
circle.c:9:19: warning: (near initialization for 'vtbl.area') [enabled by default]
circle.c:9:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
circle.c:9:19: warning: (near initialization for 'vtbl.lenght') [enabled by default]
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:14:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'k1.super.vptr->lenght' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     k1.super.vptr->lenght(&k1);
     ^
main.c:14:5: note: expected 'struct Shape *' but argument is of type 'struct rect *'
main.c:15:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'd1.super.vptr->lenght' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     d1.super.vptr->lenght(&d1);
     ^
main.c:15:5: note: expected 'struct Shape *' but argument is of type 'struct circle *'
rect.c: In function 'rect_ctor':
rect.c:9:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
     static struct Vtable vtbl = { &rect_area, &rect_lenght };
                   ^
rect.c:9:19: warning: (near initialization for 'vtbl.area') [enabled by default]
rect.c:9:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
rect.c:9:19: warning: (near initialization for 'vtbl.lenght') [enabled by default]
/tmp % ./a.out
rectangle lenght: 70
circle lenght: 31.400000
/tmp %
```

Modifying *main* to allocate the elements in the heap to allow *valgrind* to know they size to detect possible accesses out of them :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "rect.h"
#include "circle.h"

int main() {
    rect  * k1 = malloc(sizeof(*k1));
    circle * d1 = malloc(sizeof(*d1));

    rect_ctor(k1, 10, 10, 15, 20);
    circle_ctor(d1, 10, 10, 5);
    
    
    k1->super.vptr->lenght(k1);
    d1->super.vptr->lenght(d1);
    
    free(k1);
    free(d1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
/tmp % valgrind ./a.out
==53229== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==53229== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==53229== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==53229== Command: ./a.out
==53229== 
rectangle lenght: 70
circle lenght: 31.400000
==53229== 
==53229== HEAP SUMMARY:
==53229==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==53229==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 48 bytes allocated
==53229== 
==53229== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==53229== 
==53229== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==53229== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
/tmp %
```

---

To not have all these warnings when compiling I encourage you to add the needed casts.

---

Note to define the *vtbl* is also better, you do not want to have them destructed by error, so

```
void shape_ctor(Shape* me,int x, int y) {   
    static const struct Vtable vtbl = { &area,&lenght };

void circle_ctor(circle* me, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t r) {
    static const struct Vtable vtbl = {&circle_area,&circle_lenght};
```

and in *shape.h* :

```
typedef struct{
    const struct Vtable* vptr;
```

The more you can declare member/variable/parameter `const` the better it is including to detect error when compiling.

Comment: Using "const" and "static" keywords was the solution. Thank you. But don't you recommend using inline function? They used inline in all the examples I saw.

Comment: @Cemal they are not used inline at all, used inline means the call is/can-be replaced by the body, but you use them through pointer to them, so you need them 'really' defined

Comment: @Cemal you welcome, I UV your question because out of the error the question and used implementation is interesting, that remember me when long time ago I implemented the small C interpreter in [xcoral](http://xcoral.free.fr/) where for instance 'eval' is polymorphic